# Как передавать значения между переменными на странице и между страницами сайта?

Tags: javascript, php, интернет-магазин, передача-данных, корзина

Пытаюсь создать подобие интернет-магазина. С помощью php подтягиваю данные с бд и создаю карточки товаров. В одной карточке может быть множество настроек типо "красная кружка высотой 9см" следующая "Жёлтая кружка высотой 13" см" (это всё одна кружка просто с разными "настройками"). Пользователь нажимает на нужную "настройку" и данные должны передаться в другое место той же самой страницы чтоб пользователь мог более детально глянуть и выбрать количество товара, а после выбранные данные должны передаться на другую страницу в "корзину" где эти данные отправятся на почту и т.д.
В общем стандартный функционал магазина: 1) Выбрать товар 2)Выбрать кол-во 3) Отправить в корзинку (на другую страницу).
Я предполагаю что надо как то полученные данные с php конвертировать и передать как то в JS, а когда потребуется отправить данные на почту, то опять их отправить в php. Может кто то сможет рассказать более правильно подсказать как реализовать подобный функционал (я занимаюсь таким впервые) или хотя бы направит(ссылка видео или на нужную статью тоже подойдёт).

Comment: Для передачи данных с одной страницы на другую PHP не обязателен. Почитайте об этом в этой статье: [Передача данных в html-файл:](https://www.spravkaweb.ru/javascript/sovet/get)